# How to import `bulma-carousel` library in Nuxt 3 project

Tags: nuxt.js, bulma, nuxtjs3

**I'm trying to use [`bulma-carousel`](https://bulma-carousel.onrender.com/) library in my Nuxt 3-RC13 project** but I'm getting errors everywhere.

I tried first to import `bulma-carousel` directly in `index.vue` page but it throws a `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. Now I'm trying to import `bulma-carousel` library as a plugin but it's throwing another error `[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] TypeError: $slider is not a function`.

I've 'googled' this problem and found some similar issues here (in stackoverflow I mean) and tried the solutions but they didn't work for me. Please any help much be really appreciate it!. Am I doing something wrong? missing something? please help.

This is the first trying (that throws `ReferenceError: window is not defined`):
`index.vue` with no plugin, just importing the library in it

```html
<script setup>
import bulmaCarousel from 'bulma-carousel'

bulmaCarousel.attach('#carousel-demo', {
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 4,
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <section class="hero is-medium has-carousel">
      <div id="carousel-demo" class="hero-carousel">
        <div class="item-1">
          <!-- Slide Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="item-2">
          <!-- Slide Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="item-3">
          <!-- Slide Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero-head"></div>
      <div class="hero-body"></div>
      <div class="hero-foot"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is the second trying (that throws `[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] TypeError: $slider is not a function`):

`slider.client.ts` plugin for trying to provide `bulma-carousel` as a helper function

```js
// @ts-nocheck
import bulmaCarousel from 'bulma-carousel'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: {
      slider: (id: string, options: object) =>
        bulmaCarousel.attach(id, options),
    },
  }
})
```

`index.vue`

```html
<script setup>
const { $slider } = useNuxtApp()

$slider('carousel-demo', {
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  slidesToShow: 4,
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <section class="hero is-medium has-carousel">
      <div id="carousel-demo" class="hero-carousel">
        <div class="item-1">
          <!-- Slide Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="item-2">
          <!-- Slide Content -->
        </div>
        <div class="item-3">
          <!-- Slide Content -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero-head"></div>
      <div class="hero-body"></div>
      <div class="hero-foot"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!</p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```